# Turn <cflocation> redirects ON and OFF?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, lucee

I have a legacy ColdFusion system with over 200 `<cflocation>` tags, and would like to be able to easily turn them all off for testing purposes from within my `Application.cfm`.

What would be the best way to do this other than having to add a conditional statement to every file?

The thought of extending the `<cflocation>` tag to first check a `true`/`false` flag came to mind, but I have never done anything that advanced before, and have no idea where to start.

Comment: This is not possible. You cannot just globally override tags. You will need to deal with them conditionally like any other code.

Comment: Can't extend tags either. You can create your own custom tag and try a search/replace, but who knows what kind of developer nightmare you'd have at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot extend/inherit native tags in CF. You could go with [a custom tag](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/building-blocks-of-coldfusion-applications/creating-and-using-custom-cfml-tags/creating-custom-tags.html) and then search-replace all occurences of `<cflocation` (native) with `<cf_location` (custom) having your redirect flag inside of it.

##### Application.cfm

```
<cfset APPLICATION.allowRedirects = false>
```

##### location.cfm (wrapper for native `cflocation`)

```
<!--- if the variable doesn't exist for some reason, process the regular cflocation --->
<cfif (
    (not isDefined("APPLICATION.allowRedirects")) or
    (isBoolean(APPLICATION.allowRedirects) and APPLICATION.allowRedirects)
)>
    <cflocation attributeCollection="#ATTRIBUTES#">
    <!--- cflocation ends the request automatically --->
</cfif>

<!--- print debug info --->
<cfif structKeyExists(ATTRIBUTES, "url")>
    <cfoutput>Attempted to redirect to: #encodeForHtml(ATTRIBUTES["url"])#</cfoutput>
</cfif>

<!--- abort the request without redirecting --->
<cfabort>
```

Another approach would be [`<cfmodule>`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfmodule.html). Search-replace all occurences of `<cflocation` with `<cfmodule template="/mytags/location.cfm"`. Advantage here: You don't need to register `location.cfm` via `customTagPaths` since `cfmodule` works via template path.

---

Even simpler: Just search-replace all of your `<cflocation>` tags in one go and wrap them in a conditional. You won't have to go through your 200 files manually.

*(This is for Sublime Text, but any proper editor can do this for you.)*
**Find**: `(<cflocation[^>]+>)` (enable RegEx!)
**Replace**: `<cfif APPLICATION.allowRedirects>\1</cfif>`
(`\1` is the backreference, some editors use `$1` instead)

Comment: Thank you for the great detailed explanation!

I am actually surprised to hear that the core CF tags cannot be extended.  I thought pretty much ALL languages could do that.  I guess that is why I have never done it. 

I was also hoping there might be a way to simply DISABLE it, but I am guessing that is not possible either.  I wonder how my hosting company disables specific tags so they are not available.  It must be something super CUSTOM.

I am already very familiar with Find & Replace, but I didn't want to COMMIT that many files to the repo for something irrelevant to the system.

Comment: I guess I am going to just write a custom CFC, and perform the logic in there.

Again, thank you for taking the time to respond!

-Sergio

Comment: `how my hosting company disables specific tags so they are not available` Probably using the CF's sandbox security. IIRC when enabled, the server throws an error when a restricted tag is encountered in code.  Probably not what you need here.